# Laravel Update Many-to-Many Foreign Key Record

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have `User`, `Role`, and `User_Role` table with many-to-many relationship between User and Role table.

```
class User extends Model {
    public function roles {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
    }
}

class Role extends Model {
    public function users {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
}

User
- id
- other_columns

Role
- id
- other_columns

User_Role
- id
- user_id
- role_id
- other_columns
```

**`User_Role` can have multiple same record with different `Role_User.id`.**

How to update `User`'s role without changing or deleting record of `User_Role` table? Or in other word how to update `User_Role.role_id` without changing or deleting `User_Role.id`?

I have tried:

```
$user->roles()->updateExistingPivot($userRoleId, ['role_id' => $newRoleId]);
```

and

```
$user->roles()->sync($userRoleId, ['id' => $userRoleId, 'role_id' => $newRoleId, 'user_id' => $userId]);
```

But they don't work.

**Update**

This code is work, but it also changes same other record.

```
$user->roles()->updateExistingPivot($oldRoleId, ['role_id' => $newRoleId]);
```

And I have tried to filter first

```
$user->roles()->wherePivot('id', $userRoleId)->updateExistingPivot($oldRoleId, ['role_id' => $newRoleId]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [`updateExistingPivot()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships)

```
$user->roles()->updateExistingPivot($roleId, ['role_id' => $newRoleId]);
```

If you're using more than one pair of exactly the same `user_id` and `role_id` and you want to update only one row, try to use [`newPivotStatement()`](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/5.3/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsToMany.php#L1247):

```
$user->roles()->newPivotStatement()->where('id', $userRoleId)->update(['role_id' => $newRoleId]);
```

And solution by @Yosua Lijanto Binar:

```
$user->roles()->wherePivot('id', $userRoleId)->updateExistingPivot($oldRoleId, ['role_id' => $newRoleId]);
```

Comment: Oh, you've updated your question with `updateExistingPivot()`. I wonder what is `$userRoleId` in your example? It's an old role ID?

Comment: It is primary key of User_Role table.

Comment: So, it's `id` column in pivot table? If so, try to use old role ID instead.

Comment: Yes, thank you it works. But It also change the other same record. Example: `User_Role(id->1, user_id->1, role_id->1)`, `User_Role(id->2, user_id->2, role_id->2)` then I run that code. It change 2 record. Any solutions?

Comment: You mean you have two rows with the same `user_id` and `role_id`?

Comment: Thank you, it works. And also I have my solution too, because of you (in updated question). Please add them too at your answer.